# HP 2133 Video Resolution Problem in LUbuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04 LTS)

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, 18.04, display-resolution

First of all: I know this is a **VERY OLD** Netbook. However, due to it's "compactness", it's my perfect companion while wandering thru the Datacenter patching / fixing / whatever. This Model was sold with Windows Vista, which in due time I replaced with Windows XP (and it was pretty fast). Problem is, XP is looong dead now.

I installed LUbuntu 18.04 LTS on this machine, and everything worked fine, except for Video Display, which required to install "xserver-xorg-video-openchrome" package, which I did.

Now I get Full Display support, **BUT**... This Netbook's Native 1024x600 Screen is detected as "1024x768" capable (by xorg), and thus, the lower 168 Lines of Desktop fall OUTSIDE the Screen, to the bottom!

I've researched the Net looking for solutions to this, and I have found some (very old) ones, that needed me to modify the "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" file, which has no longer existed for quite some time now (and I'm UNSURE of how to make xorg to revert to use an static xorg.conf).

I think this may be related to [this old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/+bug/355918) (implicating Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY Wi-Fi Card), as I first tried Lubuntu 17.10.1 (Artful Aardvark) on this machine (as a test), and then Wi-Fi Connectivity was a non-working bloody mess, but Video Display was **correctly** autoconfigured with 1024x600 Resolution.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 Host Bridge
00:00.1 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 Host Bridge
00:00.2 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 Host Bridge
00:00.3 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 Host Bridge
00:00.4 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 Host Bridge
00:00.5 PIC: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 I/O APIC Interrupt Controller
00:00.6 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 Security Device
00:00.7 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237/VX700 PCI Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 PCI to PCI Bridge Controller (rev 80)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 PCI to PCI Bridge Controller (rev 80)
00:0f.0 IDE interface: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237/8251 Serial ATA Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev b0)
00:10.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev b0)
00:10.3 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xx/62xx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev b0)
00:10.4 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 90)
00:11.0 ISA bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237S PCI to ISA Bridge
00:11.7 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237/8251 Ultra VLINK Controller
00:13.0 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A Host Bridge
00:13.1 PCI bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A PCI to PCI Bridge
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 [Chrome 9 HC] (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
07:03.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 03)
80:01.0 Audio device: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller (rev 10)
```

Here is the output of **lsusb**:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b107 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF7070 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And, from my current `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, line #230, it can be seen that xorg autodetects my screen as one with Native Resolution 1024x768:

```
(Line #230) --> [    37.775] (II) CHROME(0): Flat Panel Native Resolution: 1024x768
```

Here is the full [Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/Rfzx2Arm) file (look at Line #223 in this PasteBin).

I **really** hope someone could help me. By the way: could I gain something by manually downloading AND compiling the latest driver version from [OpenChrome Developers](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Openchrome), as I've read somewhere...?

Comment: Sorry, can't post my full my current "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" file, as it has over 50.000 characters... :/

Comment: For the moment, I can use my Netbook by moving the "Task Bar" to the top of the Screen, but this is just cosmetic palliative. "Full Screen" Applications are gonna be a hassle, manually resizing Windows to match physical screen edges.

Comment: I can add that, if I switch to the Text Console (CTRL-ALL-F1 to F6), the Console gets the Screen size right.

Comment: Another problem I've just run into: If I leave Netbook idle for a while, and Screen enters Power Saving Mode, Networking DIES, both Wi-Fi AND Ethernet.

have to issue a "sudo service network-manager restart" every time this happens in order to go back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I handle virtually all the OpenChrome graphics stack development, and I can say that I have got OpenChrome DDX running on HP 2133 mini-note (Xubuntu 18.04).

I did observe initial installation issues myself when I performed a fresh install recently due to two fairly new (a little over a year old) SSDs suddenly dying in a span of a week (ADATA Ultimate SU800 128 GB and 256 GB models), but I was able to install by disabling ACPI, although after installing Ubuntu, one really needs to have ACPI running (Warning: If you disable ACPI when installing Ubuntu, it will pass that setting to the installed Ubuntu installation. It is important to remove the setting that disables ACPI for standby to work properly.)

If you wanted to, you could file a bug report with launchpad.net or bugs.freedesktop.org.

---

Update:

I researched the matter further and it appears that some models shipped with a 1024x600 screen resolution panel.
The model I have comes with a 1280x768 panel that has EDID support.
You should open a bug case with launchpad.net or bugs.freedesktop.org.

Answer (score 0):

The Lubuntu 17.10 WLAN not working was due to OpenChrome DDX shipping with Version 0.5.
Unfortunately, I broke VN896 chipset FP / PCIe interface in that version, so the only realistic way to fix it is to compile upstream DDX.
Version 0.6 fixed this bug since someone brought it to my attention.
Sorry for the mistake.

Kevin Brace
[Brace Computer Laboratory blog](https://bracecomputerlab.com)

Comment: I take then, I no longer need to file a Bug Report myself?

Either, compile it from Sources myself, or just sit and wait for an updated Ubuntu Driver Package to become available...?

Comment: Guess what...? Finally had spare time to compile & install OpenChrome DDX Driver from GIT Sources, and... **Same problem persists...!**

@kevin-brace - Is there some place in the Source Code I may hack, in order to force the Driver to come up with a Resolution of 1024x600 instead of 1024x768...?

Comment: A quick look at the Sources, shows many lines with "1024x768", but none with "1024x600". Really, I wouldn't know what to modify by myself.